# Haskell: OpenGL, how to prevent immediate window closing

Tags: haskell, opengl, functional-programming, graphics

Whenever I close OpenGL window it makes `ghci` console from which the app was started to immediately disappear. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? [A sample app](http://bitbucket.org/yasir/haskell/src/tip/sphere_approx/lit_sphere_thr.hs).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before calling mainLoop, you can change the actionOnWindowClose mode :

```
actionOnWindowClose $= MainLoopReturns

mainLoop
```

Don't know if it works for non-Linux users.

Comment: @saul: It fails to run properly with message `*** Exception: user error (unknown GLUT call glutSetOption, check for freeglut)` in Windows though. People described the problem in [comments here](http://netsuperbrain.com/blog/posts/freeglut-windows-hopengl-hglut). Thanks for pointing to a solution anyway, and there are backticks for code. ;)